# How do I backup my wallet with bitcoin-cli over RPC?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, backup

```
hendry@knuckles ~ $ bitcoin-cli backupwallet /home/hendry/backup.dat
error code: -1
error message:
boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/home/hendry/backup.dat"
```

Reddit couldn't help me https://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinBeginners/comments/aftb91/am_i_running_bitcoin_core/

This is no permission problem.

```
hendry@knuckles ~ $ touch backup.dat
hendry@knuckles ~ $ ls backup.dat
backup.dat
hendry@knuckles ~ $ rm backup.dat
```

I suspect the `bitcoind -server` which runs in isolation as "nobody" is trying to access my home directory, which is a bit of a concern. My user's .bitcoin directory looks fine:

```
hendry@knuckles ~ $ find .bitcoin/
.bitcoin/
.bitcoin/mempool.dat
.bitcoin/wallets
.bitcoin/wallets/wallet.dat
.bitcoin/wallets/db.log
.bitcoin/wallets/.walletlock
.bitcoin/.lock
.bitcoin/chainstate
.bitcoin/chainstate/000003.log
.bitcoin/chainstate/CURRENT
.bitcoin/chainstate/MANIFEST-000002
.bitcoin/chainstate/LOCK
.bitcoin/fee_estimates.dat
.bitcoin/banlist.dat
.bitcoin/blocks
.bitcoin/blocks/index
.bitcoin/blocks/index/000003.log
.bitcoin/blocks/index/CURRENT
.bitcoin/blocks/index/000004.log
.bitcoin/blocks/index/MANIFEST-000002
.bitcoin/blocks/index/LOCK
.bitcoin/blocks/index/000005.ldb
.bitcoin/blocks/rev00000.dat
.bitcoin/blocks/blk00000.dat
.bitcoin/peers.dat
.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
.bitcoin/debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The process writing the file is `bitcoind`, not `bitcoin-cli`, which is simply issuing RPC commands to the server.`bitcoind` needs to be able to write to the destination, which can’t be another users home folders unless you explicitly give it permission.

Comment: I don't understand this model. I have my private ~/.bitcoin directory with my private stuff there I hope. I interact with the blockchain with bitcoind. It makes no sense for the bitcoind to be able to write to my home folder from my perspective.

Comment: The file list you posted is not of a synchronised node, by the way.

Comment: synchronized afaict https://s.natalian.org/2019-01-19/1547890087_2548x1398.png